# AWS managment console does not allow to modify headers or implement CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I've successfully implemented a set of API gateway methods and Lambda integrations. However, when attempting to add a new resource and method since few weeks, I encountered an issue. Despite selecting the option to allow CORS, the resources are being created with OPTIONS WITHOUT CORS. Additionally, if I try to enable CORS, a red bar appears at the top stating 'Failed to add CORS.' Manually adding headers also results in a network failure. Currently, I'm unable to find a solution for adding CORS.

Example:
[failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETKRS.png)

I tried asking on AWS re:post but nobody answered, and tried the free support, but they said nobody will look into my account without paid support tier.

The problem is I think I am doing everything properly, and that AWS blocked something in my account.